# Yelp API call from Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oauth, yelp

I've got some code in node js that i need for a simple web app that i'm working on, however it needs to be written in typescript. The app i am working on will call the yelp api and receive data on food deals around an input location. I'm unsure about how to write up this code in typescript and how it will integrate with the html/css side of things. Or is there a better way to make a yelp API call using Typescript? This is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var OAuth = require('oauth-request');
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));// checks for environment variable port

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});

app.get('/getdealsforlocation', function (req, res) {
  var data = OAuth({
      consumer: {
          public: 'zyiAgV9Jbea1BSrpVPFl0w',
          secret: 's-jcY90vXvG9UOx8pYE8g0WOosw'
      }
  });

  data.setToken({
      public: 'vfZcastyjgwkfXaDKtczSLY8JVBW943B',
      secret: 'F8-P5ZsXTkhEH_brQfVdeZAPLDs'
  });

//list user timeline
  data.get('https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?cll='+ req.query.lat + ',' + req.query.lon +'&location=' + req.query.location + '&deals_filter=true&term=food&radius_filter='+35000, function(err, thing, data) {//req.query.radius_filter, function(err, thing, data) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      }
      var filteredData = filterData(JSON.parse(data))//(data);
      res.send(filteredData);//data);
  });
});

app.get('/hello', function(request, response) {
    response.send('Hello World!')
});

function filterData(data) { //data from API call is fed in
  var filteredData = []; //array for filtered data
  var businesses = data.businesses;
  businesses.map(function(business){//loops through each element in businesses array
      var businessObject = {};//create businessObject which will store the details of a business
      businessObject.name = business.name;
      businessObject.deals = business.deals;
      businessObject.address = business.location.display_address;
      businessObject.coordinates = business.location.coordinate
      filteredData.push(businessObject);//appends businessObject into the filteredData array
  });
  return filteredData;

}

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {//listens on allocated port
  console.log('Example app listening on port ' + app.get('port') + '!');
});
```